# OEIS entry - A316312 has a question: Is it true that if k is a term then 100 * k is a term?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, discrete-mathematics, recreational-mathematics, computational-mathematics

Refer https://oeis.org/A316312 - the sequence in OEIS.

The sequence says

> Numbers n such that sum of the digits of the numbers 1, 2, 3, ... up
> to (n - 1) is divisible by n.

A few terms from the sequence are as follows:
1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 12, 15, 20, 27, 40, 45, 60, 63, 80, 81, 100, 180, 181, 300, 360, 363, 500, 540, 545, 700, 720, 727, 900, 909, 912, 915, 1137, 1140, 1200, 1500, 1560, 1563, 2000, 2700, 2720, 2727, 4000, 4500, 4540, 4545, 6000, 6300, 6360, 6363, 8000, 8100, 8180, ...

It is evident from the sequence that if k is a term then 100*k is also a term. We (Author of the sequence and another Math nerd from GanitCharcha) haven't been able to prove or disprove it and we also do not know whether this has been proved or disproved.

If anyone can help us in this regard by providing pointers or any solution.

Comment: Who is we?  What have you (collectively?) tried?  Is there any reason to imagine that this is true?  Even the results of a deep computer search might help.

Comment: @DietrichBurde all numbers $n$ in the table up to $10,000$ have $100n$ in the table.  The cumulative digit sum to $72700-1$ is $1526700=21 \times 72700$

Answer (score 10):

Let $a(n)$ be the function in question. Then

$$a(100n) = 100a(n) +na(100)$$
Since $a(100)$ is a multiple of $100$, we have that if $a(n)$ is a multiple of $n$, then $a(100n)$ is also a multiple of $100n$.

Answer (score 6):

Yes it seems to be true.

Suppose $n$ is in $A316312$ and the cumulative digit sum up to $n-1$ is $d$;

the cumulative digit sum up to $100-1$ is $900$ so the cumulative digit sum up to $100n-1$ is $900n+100d = 100(9n+d)$.

Since $d$ is divisible by $n$ in $A316312$, we have $100(9n+d)$ being divisible by $100n$.